# Get successive row values without loop in SQL

Tags: sql, window-functions, ddl, vertica, case-statement

I have the following table:

| AppId | Id | Direction | Text | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| aaa | 11 | in | hello | 11/2/2021 3:03:00 PM |
| aaa | 22 | out | yes? | 11/2/2021 3:04:00 PM |
| aaa | 33 | in | need help! | 11/3/2021 3:06:00 PM |
| aaa | 44 | in | you there? | 11/4/2021 3:10:00 PM |
| aaa | 55 | out | yes! | 11/5/2021 4:00:00 PM |
| bb | 111 | out | welcome! | 11/6/2021 6:09:00 PM |
| bb | 222 | in | can i call? | 11/6/2021 6:39:00 PM |
| bb | 333 | out | sure. | 11/6/2021 8:22:00 PM |
| cc | 1111 | out | hello? | 11/8/2021 2:22:00 PM |
| cc | 2222 | in | Whatsup! | 11/8/2021 3:22:00 PM |

Id is a primary key, direction is basically telling us if it is an incoming message or outgoing. App id is to identify various ids that are part of a single conversation. I want to identify the first response time after an incoming message as:

| AppId | Id | Direction | Text | Date | ReplyDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| aaa | 11 | in | hello | 11/2/2021 3:03:00 PM | 11/2/2021 3:04:00 PM |
| aaa | 22 | out | yes? | 11/2/2021 3:04:00 PM | null |
| aaa | 33 | in | need help! | 11/3/2021 3:06:00 PM | 11/5/2021 4:00:00 PM |
| aaa | 44 | in | you there? | 11/4/2021 3:10:00 PM | 11/5/2021 4:00:00 PM |
| aaa | 55 | out | yes! | 11/5/2021 4:00:00 PM | null |
| bb | 111 | out | welcome! | 11/6/2021 6:09:00 PM | null |
| bb | 222 | in | can i call? | 11/6/2021 6:39:00 PM | 11/6/2021 8:22:00 PM |
| bb | 333 | out | sure. | 11/6/2021 8:22:00 PM | null |
| cc | 1111 | out | hello? | 11/8/2021 2:22:00 PM | null |
| cc | 2222 | in | Whatsup! | 11/8/2021 3:22:00 PM | null |

For any 'out' text the reply column is null, but for every 'in' text it brings the next latest timestamp for 'out'. If there is no outcoming text following an incoming text then the 'ReplyDate' for incoming is also null as in the case of 'cc'.

Can this be done in SQL. I am using vertica and it doesn't allow recursive or loop statements so I must achieve this without them.

I have been able to use lead () to get when the next one is outcoming text but not able to fill it for all previous incoming texts.

This is what I have tried so far but this doesn't get me the required result:

```
with cte as (
select 
row_number() over(partition by AppId order by date asc) as rn,
Id,
AppId
Direction,
Text,
Date,
lead(Direction, 1) over(order by Date asc) as lead_direction,
lead(Date, 1) over (order by Date asc) as lead_date,
from table
order by Date desc)
select 
Id,
AppId
Direction,
Text
Date,
case when Direction = 'Out' then null
     when lead_direction = null then null
     when rn <> 1 and Direction = 'In' and Direction = lead_direction then null
     when rn <> 1 and Direction = 'In' and Direction <> lead_direction then lead_date
     end as ReplyDate
from cte
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thank you for this nice challenge. I think it's a candidate for Vertica's `MATCH()` clause, albeit not so straightforward. But it's a fascinating task ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Took a few attempts, but now I think I got it.
The first CTE in the `WITH` clause is not part of the final query - it's just putting your original input into a self contained demo query.

The real query, and the real `WITH` clause starts after that.

As the closing 'out' row for each 'in' row can come one, two, or several rows later, this can be solved with a behavioural pattern: one or more 'in' rows, followed by one 'out' row. That's what the `MATCH()` clause is for.
Only rows fulfilling the pattern are returned in the query containing the clause.

The depending function `PATTERN_ID()` returns the ordinal number of the found pattern within the `PARTITION BY... ORDER BY` expression.

GROUPing by the `PARTITION BY` columns and the `PATTERN_ID` will help me get the last timestamp of the pattern, which I need for the `replyts` (I changed the column names to avoid reserved words like `DATE` or `TEXT`).

At the end, I just need to left join the `indata` CTE with the query containing the `MATCH()` clause, on equality of the `id` column and the `direction` being equal to 'in', and that second query with the grouping query.

I left the intermediate result as an illustration of the mechanism within the CTE expressions ...

```
WITH
-- input from you ...
indata(AppId,Id,Direction,txt,ts) AS (
          SELECT 'aaa',11,'in','hello',TIMESTAMP '11/2/2021 3:03:00 PM'
UNION ALL SELECT 'aaa',22,'out','yes?',TIMESTAMP '11/2/2021 3:04:00 PM'
UNION ALL SELECT 'aaa',33,'in','need help!',TIMESTAMP '11/3/2021 3:06:00 PM'
UNION ALL SELECT 'aaa',44,'in','you there?',TIMESTAMP '11/4/2021 3:10:00 PM'
UNION ALL SELECT 'aaa',55,'out','yes!',TIMESTAMP '11/5/2021 4:00:00 PM'
UNION ALL SELECT 'bb',111,'out','welcome!',TIMESTAMP '11/6/2021 6:09:00 PM'
UNION ALL SELECT 'bb',222,'in','can i call?',TIMESTAMP '11/6/2021 6:39:00 PM'
UNION ALL SELECT 'bb',333,'out','sure.',TIMESTAMP '11/6/2021 8:22:00 PM'
UNION ALL SELECT 'cc',1111,'out','hello?',TIMESTAMP '11/8/2021 2:22:00 PM'
UNION ALL SELECT 'cc',2222,'in','Whatsup!',TIMESTAMP '11/8/2021 3:22:00 PM'
)
-- real query starts here, replace following comma with "WITH" ...
,
-- the MATCH() clause in action - note the depending functions
-- PATTERN_ID(), MATCH_ID() and EVENT_NAME()
pattern_q AS (
  SELECT 
    appid
  , id
  , direction
  , txt
  , ts
  , PATTERN_ID()
  , MATCH_ID()
  , EVENT_NAME()
  FROM indata
  MATCH(
    PARTITION BY appid ORDER BY id
    DEFINE
      inbound  AS direction='in'
    , outbound AS direction='out'
    PATTERN
      p AS (inbound+ outbound)
  )
  -- out  appid   | id  | direction |     txt     |         ts          | PATTERN_ID | MATCH_ID | EVENT_NAME 
  -- out ---------+-----+-----------+-------------+---------------------+------------+----------+------------
  -- out  aaa     |  11 | in        | hello       | 2021-11-02 15:03:00 |          1 |        1 | inbound
  -- out  aaa     |  22 | out       | yes?        | 2021-11-02 15:04:00 |          1 |        2 | outbound
  -- out  aaa     |  33 | in        | need help!  | 2021-11-03 15:06:00 |          2 |        1 | inbound
  -- out  aaa     |  44 | in        | you there?  | 2021-11-04 15:10:00 |          2 |        2 | inbound
  -- out  aaa     |  55 | out       | yes!        | 2021-11-05 16:00:00 |          2 |        3 | outbound
  -- out  bb      | 222 | in        | can i call? | 2021-11-06 18:39:00 |          1 |        1 | inbound
  -- out  bb      | 333 | out       | sure.       | 2021-11-06 20:22:00 |          1 |        2 | outbound
)
,
-- need the last timestamp per PATTERN_ID() ... so grouping
pattern_grp AS (
  SELECT
    appid
  , pattern_id
  , MIN(ts) AS g_ts
  , MAX(ts) AS replyts
  FROM pattern_q
  GROUP BY
    appid
  , pattern_id
  -- out  appid | pattern_id |         ts          |       replyts       
  -- out -------+------------+---------------------+---------------------
  -- out  aaa   |          1 | 2021-11-02 15:03:00 | 2021-11-02 15:04:00
  -- out  aaa   |          2 | 2021-11-03 15:06:00 | 2021-11-05 16:00:00
  -- out  bb    |          1 | 2021-11-06 18:39:00 | 2021-11-06 20:22:00
)
SELECT
  i.*
, g.replyts
FROM indata           i
LEFT JOIN pattern_q   p ON i.id = p.id       AND i.direction='in'
LEFT JOIN pattern_grp g ON p.appid = g.appid AND p.pattern_id = g.pattern_id 
-- out Null display is "(null)".
-- out  AppId |  Id  | Direction |     txt     |         ts          |       replyts       
-- out -------+------+-----------+-------------+---------------------+---------------------
-- out  aaa   |   11 | in        | hello       | 2021-11-02 15:03:00 | 2021-11-02 15:04:00
-- out  aaa   |   22 | out       | yes?        | 2021-11-02 15:04:00 | (null)
-- out  aaa   |   33 | in        | need help!  | 2021-11-03 15:06:00 | 2021-11-05 16:00:00
-- out  aaa   |   44 | in        | you there?  | 2021-11-04 15:10:00 | 2021-11-05 16:00:00
-- out  aaa   |   55 | out       | yes!        | 2021-11-05 16:00:00 | (null)
-- out  bb    |  111 | out       | welcome!    | 2021-11-06 18:09:00 | (null)
-- out  bb    |  222 | in        | can i call? | 2021-11-06 18:39:00 | 2021-11-06 20:22:00
-- out  bb    |  333 | out       | sure.       | 2021-11-06 20:22:00 | (null)
-- out  cc    | 1111 | out       | hello?      | 2021-11-08 14:22:00 | (null)
-- out  cc    | 2222 | in        | Whatsup!    | 2021-11-08 15:22:00 | (null)
```

Comment: This is amazing the way you came up with the logic, I was trying to build a pattern only and I was unable to bring the logic together, but this works. Thanks for your time and sharing your knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

Although this solution is not the cleanest one, but it gets the job done.

```sql
WITH
main_data AS (
                  SELECT 'aaa' as AppId,11 as Id,'in' as Direction ,'hello' AS Text,'11/2/2021 3:03:00 PM' AS DATE_TEXT
        UNION ALL SELECT 'aaa' as AppId,22 as Id,'out'as Direction ,'yes?' AS Text,'11/2/2021 3:04:00 PM' AS DATE_TEXT
        UNION ALL SELECT 'aaa' as AppId,33 as Id,'in' as Direction ,'need help!' AS Text,'11/3/2021 3:06:00 PM' AS DATE_TEXT
        UNION ALL SELECT 'aaa' as AppId,44 as Id,'in' as Direction ,'you there?' AS Text,'11/4/2021 3:10:00 PM' AS DATE_TEXT
        UNION ALL SELECT 'aaa' as AppId,55 as Id,'out' as Direction ,'yes!' AS Text,'11/5/2021 4:00:00 PM' AS DATE_TEXT
        UNION ALL SELECT 'bb'  as AppId,111 AS ID,'out' as Direction ,'welcome!' AS Text,'11/6/2021 6:09:00 PM' AS DATE_TEXT
        UNION ALL SELECT 'bb'  as AppId,222 AS ID,'in' as Direction ,'can i call?' AS Text,'11/6/2021 6:39:00 PM' AS DATE_TEXT
        UNION ALL SELECT 'bb'  as AppId,333 AS ID,'out' as Direction ,'sure.' AS Text,'11/6/2021 8:22:00 PM' AS DATE_TEXT
        UNION ALL SELECT 'cc'  as AppId,1111AS ID,'out' as Direction ,'hello?' AS Text,'11/8/2021 2:22:00 PM' AS DATE_TEXT
        UNION ALL SELECT 'cc'  as AppId,2222AS ID,'in' as Direction ,'Whatsup!' AS Text,'11/8/2021 3:22:00 PM' AS DATE_TEXT
    )
, temp_data AS (SELECT AppId
        , Id
        , Direction
        , TEXT
        , DATE_TEXT
        , CONDITIONAL_TRUE_EVENT(Direction = 'out') OVER (PARTITION BY AppId ORDER BY Id) as rank_logic
    FROM main_data
    )
SELECT t1.AppId
    , t1.Id
    , t1.Direction
    , t1.TEXT
    , t1.DATE_TEXT
    , t2.DATE_TEXT
FROM temp_data t1
LEFT JOIN temp_data t2
    ON t1.AppId = t2.AppId
        AND t1.rank_logic + 1 = t2.rank_logic
        AND t2.Direction = 'out'
        AND t1.Direction <> 'out';
```

output

```
 AppId |  Id  | Direction |    TEXT     |      DATE_TEXT       |      DATE_TEXT       
-------+------+-----------+-------------+----------------------+----------------------
 aaa   |   11 | in        | hello       | 11/2/2021 3:03:00 PM | 11/2/2021 3:04:00 PM
 aaa   |   22 | out       | yes?        | 11/2/2021 3:04:00 PM | 
 aaa   |   33 | in        | need help!  | 11/3/2021 3:06:00 PM | 11/5/2021 4:00:00 PM
 aaa   |   44 | in        | you there?  | 11/4/2021 3:10:00 PM | 11/5/2021 4:00:00 PM
 aaa   |   55 | out       | yes!        | 11/5/2021 4:00:00 PM | 
 bb    |  111 | out       | welcome!    | 11/6/2021 6:09:00 PM | 
 bb    |  222 | in        | can i call? | 11/6/2021 6:39:00 PM | 11/6/2021 8:22:00 PM
 bb    |  333 | out       | sure.       | 11/6/2021 8:22:00 PM | 
 cc    | 1111 | out       | hello?      | 11/8/2021 2:22:00 PM | 
 cc    | 2222 | in        | Whatsup!    | 11/8/2021 3:22:00 PM | 
(10 rows)
```

Comment: I would have liked to play more with logic to "session-ize" the in-out transaction, but that would have been few nested queries and some more time.

Comment: Nice, too - I tried the `MATCH()` clause, using `PATTERN_ID()` as a grouping column on an outer query ... learning a lot about the mechanism myself ...

Comment: This is nice and it works but the problem is when I have multiple ins (let say 5) between two outs, then we can't keep comparing the rank and that's why I wanted the loop feature but this is a perfect for this scenario but for universal thing, I will need pattern match. I think @marchothesane, showed it in the other answer. Thanks for this, I learnt about the CONDITIONAL_TRUE_EVENT function. Wow!